# How to build a simple journaling applications with Google-apps

Tags: google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension, google-docs-api

As the title said I want to *build* a simple application that has the following features:

1. It is activated by a menu item on the Chrome browser.
2. When clicked it will open a file with the **current date** in a *specific folder* of my Google Docs.

   a) If the file exists, then:

   - If already opened, bring it on focus
   - Otherwise, open it

   b) Otherwise, create the file with the current date in the specified directory.
3. Add a facility to search in the journal

I know how to implement most of the features, except the following:

- How to link a script to menu-item (maybe with a blank doc which just holds a script)
- How to bring an open doc to focus.

I tried to use a single file with a date insertion in tools, but after size increased, it became unusable.
All the journaling systems I found, did not provide what I was looking for.

Comment: Hey @bandi, welcome to Stackoverflow! To better understand your question, I'd like to ask you the following. 1. What you are trying to create is a Chrome Extension that has an extension button right next to the url bar to trigger it, correct? 2. When you say "open doc to focus", do you mean to open the Chrome tab that has the document open? Cheers

Comment: Yes, I think that you got the intent, but I was not aware that in order to add a button you need an extension. I was thinking to add a dummy file and add the dummy file's URL. My main stumbling block is how to bring it to focus.

Comment: Hey, have you been able to test my answer? please let me know if that's not what you are looking for. Cheers!

Comment: In fact, I did and always unexpected problems pop up. First of all, there is an error on line 19,  that it cannot find the directory. I defined in my drive, and I see it in my docs in the web view. I wanted to find the problem myself, but if you have any idea what can be nay suggestions is welcome. Maybe it would be better to add directory creation. in case of failure to access it. Also, I hope that there is no security problem if only I can access it (Google warned very aggressively when I allowed access).

Comment: Maybe it is an access problem - I allowed everything it requested.

Comment: If you can access the folder, and create files inside it - then the Script should not have any problem doing so. How are you getting the ID of the destination folder? Through the UI, if you navigate *and* open the desired folder in which to store your journals, your URL should look something like `https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/YOUR_FOLDER_ID`. Copying and pasting that ID should be enough.

Comment: Tada! it worked. My version does not have your format https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/YOUR_FOLDER_ID.

So I typed: https://drive.google.com
Google corrected it to: https://drive.google.com/drive/my-drive
Then I clicked on my directory and Google corrected it to his encrypted ID xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

I took this ID and it worked. It seems awkward. There should be a better method

Comment: It worked from the script editor. It does not work from menubar. I changed the URL it gave to that of the test code and it works from menubar. Just a hack until I will understand what is going on.

Comment: Glad to hear, @bandi :). That is somewhat awkward indeed. In order to make it work from the menubar you have to create a bookmark, and set the URL to be the one that you get from "Deploy as web app" feature. If my answer helped you, please consider [upvoting/accepting it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An easy solution that would accomplish all your needs but bringing the file into focus when it is already open, is the following:

#### Creating a Google Apps Script WebApp.

The idea here is that you can easily create a [GAS WebApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) that you can add to your browser's Bookmars Bar. Upon clicking it, it will create the daily journal file if needed and then redirect you to it. You can see the code below:

```js
var TIMEZONE = 'GMT';
var FOLDER_ID = 'YOUR_FOLDER_ID';
var FILE_NAME_FORMAT = 'yyyy-MM-dd';

function createDocFile(fileName, folder) {
  return Drive.Files.insert({
    "title":    fileName,
    "mimeType": "application/vnd.google-apps.document",
    "parents":  [{"id": folder.getId()}]
  }).alternateLink;
}


function doGet() {
  var today = new Date();
  var fileName = Utilities.formatDate(today, TIMEZONE, FILE_NAME_FORMAT);

  var fileURL;
  var folder = DriveApp.getFolderById(FOLDER_ID);
  var fileIterator = folder.getFilesByName(fileName);

  if (fileIterator.hasNext()) {
    fileURL = fileIterator.next().getUrl();
  } else {
    fileURL = createDocFile(fileName, folder);
  }

  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput('<script>window.location.href = "' + fileURL + '";</script>');
}
```

In order to make it work for you, you will have to adapt the variables declared on top as you desire.

Further to that, you will also need to enable the Drive API Advanced Google Service. To do so, you can follow the following steps:

- From the script editor, go to Resources > Advanced Google Services.
- In the window that will open, search for "*Drive API*" and enable it. Click OK.

Finally, you can deploy it going to Publish > Deploy as web app. Make sure to copy the URL that will show there and create a Bookmark in the Bookmark bar with that URL.

#### Alternative

If you really want to make it work such that the open document focuses when it already exists on your browser, you will definitely have to look into [creating Google Chrome extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview). In order to make this check work, you may be interested in using the Google Chrome extension's [windows api](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/windows).

Comment: This solution works for me, and I am happy with it. I wanted to make changes and Drive.Files.insert requires special authorizations, Also MIME.GOOFLE_DOCS option is not accepted by CreateFile. Is there any way out of this mess?